# Is there a figure with 3 non-concurent symmetry axes?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Is there a plane figure with at least **3 non-concurent** symmetry axes? Can it be a bounded figure?

P.S. There is a theorem which states that if a polygon has more than 2 axes of symmetry then all of them are concurrent at one point (see **Viktor Prasolov - Plane geometry**, *problem 17.33*)

Comment: How many dimensions? Two?

Comment: Yes. I forgot to mention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any finite 2D figure can only have a point group as symmetry group, and by definition all symmetry axes of a point group are concurrent at the titular point, so there cannot be three non-concurrent symmetry axes.

Infinite figures with translational symmetry are restricted to having frieze and wallpaper groups as symmetry groups, each of which either has infinitely many symmetry axes or none. Thus there cannot be *exactly* three non-concurrent symmetry axes here either.

---

A more direct proof of the same is to note that three non-concurrent symmetry axes either form a triangle or have two parallels, where reflecting across one axis the other two shows there has to be at least one *more* symmetry axis.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I wonder from what book I can find more about frieze and wallpaper groups? I did not heard about that untill now.

Comment: @Bogdan Go search Wikipedia lah.

Comment: "The Symmetries of Things" by Conway, Burgiel and Goodman-Strauss is worth looking out for - visually stunning, and mathematically interesting. It enumerates the wallpaper groups and shows how to recognise them (and does much else too).

Comment: @MarkBennet I think you should put that as a comment on the question, so OP is notified.

Comment: @Mark Bennet Thanks for the reference!