# Figure with 3 non-collinear centers of symmetry

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Is there a plane figure that has 3 centers of symmetry that are not collinear? (different from the entire plane)

Comment: (If you accept unbounded figures) answer yes : an infinite grid of equilateral triangles.

Comment: A similar question of yours an hour ago https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4509403/305862

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $ABC$ are the vertices of a triangle and centers of symmetry, given some $P$ in our set $E$ we have
$$ 2A-P, 2B-P, 2C-P \in E $$
hence
$$ P\pm 2(B-A),\quad P\pm 2(C-B),\quad P\pm 2(A-C)\in E$$
and more generally $P\pm 2k(B-A)\in E$ for any $k\in\mathbb{N}$, so $E$ is necessarily unbounded.
Actually only $2$ centers of symmetry are needed for this property to hold.