# Is there a plane figure with exactly two centers of symmetry?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Is there any figure in the plane which has **exactly two centers of symmetry**?

It is known that if a figure has at least two centers of symmetry then it should be unbounded. See the answer from here:[Figure with 3 non-collinear centers of symmetry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4509413/figure-with-3-non-collinear-centers-of-symmetry)

I try to imagine some figures but I always came across infinitely many centers of symmetry instead of just two.[image: my trial - infinitely many centers...]

Comment: If the figure is invariant by the symmetries $s_A$ and $s_B$, then it is invariant by $s_B \circ s_A$, which is the translation of $2\overset{\longrightarrow}AB$.

Comment: ... which is exactly what the answer to the linked question showed. And once you have translation symmetry, any centre of symmetry gets translated to infinitely many centres of symmetry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on **Christophe Leuridan's** comment:

If you have two distinct symmetry centers you also have a translational symmetry. You can apply the associated translation to one of the point symmetries arbitrarily often to produce infinitely many distinct symmetry centers.

Upshot: if you have only finitely many symmetry centers you need to have either 1 or 0. No other finite number is possible. Infinitely many are possible though.